# SSLCertVerificationError when downloading pytorch datasets via torchvision

Tags: python, ssl, pytorch

I am having trouble downloading the CIFAR-10 dataset from pytorch. Mostly it seems like some SSL error which I don't really know how to interpret. I have also tried changing the root to various other folders but none of them works. I was wondering whether it is a permission type setting on my end but I am inexperienced. Would appreciate some help to fix this!

The code executed is here:

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
```

The error is reproduced here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:1354, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1353 try:
-> 1354     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1355               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1356 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\http\client.py:1256, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1255 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1256 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\http\client.py:1302, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1301     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1302 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\http\client.py:1251, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1250     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1251 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\http\client.py:1011, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1010 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1011 self.send(msg)
   1013 if message_body is not None:
   1014 
   1015     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\http\client.py:951, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    950 if self.auto_open:
--> 951     self.connect()
    952 else:

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\http\client.py:1425, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
   1423     server_hostname = self.host
-> 1425 self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
   1426                                       server_hostname=server_hostname)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\ssl.py:500, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    494 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    495                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    496                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    497                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    498     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    499     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 500     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    501         sock=sock,
    502         server_side=server_side,
    503         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    504         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    505         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    506         context=self,
    507         session=session
    508     )

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\ssl.py:1040, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1039             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1040         self.do_handshake()
   1041 except (OSError, ValueError):

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\ssl.py:1309, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1308         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1309     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1310 finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <module>
----> 1 trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
      2 trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\cifar.py:66, in CIFAR10.__init__(self, root, train, transform, target_transform, download)
     63 self.train = train  # training set or test set
     65 if download:
---> 66     self.download()
     68 if not self._check_integrity():
     69     raise RuntimeError('Dataset not found or corrupted.' +
     70                        ' You can use download=True to download it')

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\cifar.py:144, in CIFAR10.download(self)
    142     print('Files already downloaded and verified')
    143     return
--> 144 download_and_extract_archive(self.url, self.root, filename=self.filename, md5=self.tgz_md5)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\utils.py:427, in download_and_extract_archive(url, download_root, extract_root, filename, md5, remove_finished)
    424 if not filename:
    425     filename = os.path.basename(url)
--> 427 download_url(url, download_root, filename, md5)
    429 archive = os.path.join(download_root, filename)
    430 print("Extracting {} to {}".format(archive, extract_root))

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\utils.py:130, in download_url(url, root, filename, md5, max_redirect_hops)
    127     _download_file_from_remote_location(fpath, url)
    128 else:
    129     # expand redirect chain if needed
--> 130     url = _get_redirect_url(url, max_hops=max_redirect_hops)
    132     # check if file is located on Google Drive
    133     file_id = _get_google_drive_file_id(url)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\utils.py:78, in _get_redirect_url(url, max_hops)
     75 headers = {"Method": "HEAD", "User-Agent": USER_AGENT}
     77 for _ in range(max_hops + 1):
---> 78     with urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)) as response:
     79         if response.url == url or response.url is None:
     80             return url

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:222, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220 else:
    221     opener = _opener
--> 222 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:525, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    522     req = meth(req)
    524 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 525 response = self._open(req, data)
    527 # post-process response
    528 meth_name = protocol+"_response"

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:542, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
    539     return result
    541 protocol = req.type
--> 542 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    543                           '_open', req)
    544 if result:
    545     return result

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:502, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500 for handler in handlers:
    501     func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502     result = func(*args)
    503     if result is not None:
    504         return result

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:1397, in HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)
   1396 def https_open(self, req):
-> 1397     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1398         context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pDL\lib\urllib\request.py:1357, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1354         h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1355                   encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1356     except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1357         raise URLError(err)
   1358     r = h.getresponse()
   1359 except:

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1131)>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turn off the ssl verification.

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: This is unfortunate

Comment: on Mac M1 PyCharm, after I used the two lines above I am still unable to download with torch. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of disabling the SSL validation, I was able to get past this issue by copying the download link supplied in colab and decompressing it.

[image]

If Colab can reach it but you can't, this can be a simple if not annoying workaround